# Android studio: Error: Activity not started, unknown error code 5

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

Currently developing an Android app for my company.

Everything was fine, till my last debugging session on my test-device (tablet attached to android via adb).
When I try to run or debug my app, the "Run App" log simply shows:

`Error: Activity not started, unknown error code 5`

There is no further information, no stack trace, no nothing...

I tried to figure out, what I changed since the last time, but nothing seems to fix this.

Has anybody else had this error code 5 before and can help me?

Comment: "but nothing seems to fix this" - what exactly have you tried?

Comment: I tried to clean/rebuild the project, undid changes that I made since the last time it worked. I even created a new project and moved only the code and resources over from the old project, in case something in the gradle files got damaged.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Long story short:** Unknown error 5 means (at least in my case), there is a lock (meaning a pinned app) on the device, so no other app can be started.

After a bunch of things I tried, I finally figured this out.

My app uses `startLockTask()` to pin it (so you can't accidentally press one of the navigation buttons).

The problem was, that this lock seemed to be active, even though the app wasn't running. I only realized that, after I tried to push the home button on my tablet (it already showed the android home screen, so it didn't occur to me, to try that...).

Once I released the lock (pressing both Back and Overview at the same time), I could start the debugging again, with no problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was stuck here too, this helped.

Comment: Time saving answer. perfect explanation. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Restarting the device fixed the problem